# Does refresh() need to be called at least once, when using windows in ncurses?

Tags: ncurses, curses

I've been testing ncurses, I tried doing a simple code using windows, by reading the code from the tutorials it seemed to me like calling wrefresh() was enough if changes were made just to one window. So I tried the following code, but it doesn't work, does anyone know why?

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main (void) {
    int ch;

    initscr();
    raw();
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
    noecho();

    WINDOW *my_window = newwin(10, 20, 3, 4);
    box(my_window, 0, 0);
    wrefresh(my_window);

    while ((ch=getch()) != 'q');
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

If I add an extra call to refresh() before wrefresh() everything works fine.

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main (void) {
    int ch;

    initscr();
    raw();
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
    noecho();

    WINDOW *my_window = newwin(10, 20, 3, 4);
    box(my_window, 0, 0);
    refresh();
    wrefresh(my_window);

    while ((ch=getch()) != 'q');
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

I've tried several things, for instance calling refresh() after wrefresh() doesn't work either, using only refresh() also does not work. Also [example 7](http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/Linux/docs/HOWTO/other-formats/html_single/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO.html#LETBEWINDOW) in this guide shows after calling refresh() once, it is enough to just call wrefresh() in the while loop.

Is it always mandatory to make a call to refresh() at least once after initscr()? the documentation does not seem to mention this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `getch` is the same as `wgetch(stdscr)`.  When you call `wgetch`, it refreshes the window that it uses as a parameter.  If you are trying to refresh a different window (such as `my_window`), then you should use *that* window as the parameter.

In your example, there is nothing interesting that is written to `stdscr`.  So you can omit the plain `refresh()` call.

With those changes, the program is

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main (void) {
    int ch;

    initscr();
    raw();
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
    noecho();

    WINDOW *my_window = newwin(10, 20, 3, 4);
    box(my_window, 0, 0);

    while ((ch=wgetch(my_window)) != 'q');
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

For a more interesting demo, you could write into the window.  That is best done with a *subwindow*, so that it can be scrolled, e.g.,

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main (void) {
    WINDOW *my_window;
    WINDOW *my_scroller;
    int ch;

    initscr();
    raw();
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
    noecho();

    if ((my_window = newwin(10, 20, 3, 4)) != 0) {
        box(my_window, 0, 0);
        wrefresh(my_window);
        if ((my_scroller = derwin(my_window, 8, 18, 1, 1)) != 0) {
            scrollok(my_scroller, TRUE);
            while ((ch=wgetch(my_scroller)) != 'q') {
                wprintw(my_scroller, "%#x - %s\n", ch, keyname(ch));
            }
        }
    }
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So, if I understand correctly the problem is getch() refreshes the window stdscr on top of my_window, so it effectively draws a big blank window on top of what I had previously done with wrefresh(my_window)?

Comment: yes.  It is also possible to use `touchwin` and `wrefresh` to selectively update one window.